# Is there a race condition for Database Triggers? Returning non-null values as null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is triggered when an account is created. This function populates a few fields in the user's Firebase Database entry. One of the fields is named 'accntActive', and triggers a second cloud function to do some other tasks.

In the second cloud function that gets triggered on a change of the accntActive field, the first thing I do is read the value of accntActive to check if it was changed to the value 'true'. What I am seeing is that about 50% of the time, the cloud function crashes when I try to use this value, saying it is undefined/null. Up until a week ago this always worked fine, 100% of the time, so the code itself has not changed. When I examine the user's DB entry at a later point in time, 100% of the time it has been populated correctly.

I am wondering if there is some race condition, where the DB cloud function is triggered before the value that got written is stable, and thus cannot be read immediately. This would seem a bit ridiculous, given the entire point of the DB cloud function is to respond to the value that is being changed.

The code for the second function:

```
exports.myActiveFxn = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/accntStatus/active')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const accntActive = event.data.val();
        const userID = event.params.uid;
        console.log(accntActive.toString()) //This throws an exception since accntActive is sometimes undefined
```

In the above, note that the userID variable is always stable. I've even tried re-reading the value once inside the function, and I get the same result:

```
admin.database().ref('/users/'+userID+'/accntStatus/active').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    var accntActive = snapshot.val();
    console.log(accntActive.toString());
}).then(function() {
```

Does anybody have any insight into what I can do to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is the code for the first function

```
exports.authUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(function(event) {
    var UID = event.data.uid;

    admin.database().ref('/users/'+UID).set({
        email: event.data.email,
        accntStatus: {
            active: "true",
            key: randomstring.generate(22)
        },
        uid: UID
    });

    return;
});
```

Comment: Please show the code for your first function as well.

Comment: Added the requested initiating function that triggers the DB onWrite function!

Comment: I expect Doug will provide an authoritative answer soon.  In the meantime, you need to [return a Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for the async processing in  `authUserCreated()`:  `return admin.database().ref('/users/'+UID).set(...);`.  Without it, Cloud Functions may terminate your function prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you aren't returning a promise that resolves when the work is complete.  If you don't do that, strange and inconsistent things may happen.  Please read the documentation on [async programming with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

You should return from the function the promise that's returned by the `set()` method on the database ref.

```
exports.authUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(function(event) {
    var UID = event.data.uid;

    return admin.database().ref('/users/'+UID).set({
        email: event.data.email,
        accntStatus: {
            active: "true",
            key: randomstring.generate(22)
        },
        uid: UID
    });
});
```

Comment: Update: I was incorrect. There is no null value being evaluated. That was coming from a deletion event and was unrelated (sorry!). The problem is that the cloud function is occasionally not triggered. I am adding users through a python library. It seems that when I add users too quickly, while they do get correctly added, they don't always trigger my authUserCreated function!

Is there any known issue where auth.user().onCreate triggers do not happen when accounts are created too quickly? I added a 60 second delay in between accounts getting created, and that has since "fixed" the issue.

Comment: I haven't heard of any rate limiting.  If you have an obvious bug to report, please file it with full details on how to reproduce it.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will file an issue with full details today!